# get the text of a stored procedure into a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to loop through several stored procs and extract one string form each of them to use in another procedure (basically the 4-part remote server string)

So I can get the stored procs list from `SysObjects` (with Type = P) into a table, then I can loop or cursor through that table variable calling `sp_helptext` on each one.

But how can I get the text result of `sp_helptext` into a variable so I can do a CharIndex on the word '**BOCTEST**' etc?

Is there a table like sys.procedures that stores the text.

Comment: This does not sound like a good idea. What is the use case?

Comment: Stop using sysobjects and sp_ procedures. You want `sys.sql_modules`.

Comment: @Joe that "table" does not exist. You probably meant the compatibility view `syscomments` but it should not be used - it's deprecated, could be removed at any time, and breaks the procedure up into chunks.

Comment: Sorry, yes - meant that one. And yes, it breaks the code in chunks when it passes a limit (4KB? 8KB? can't remember now). And yes, you're supposed not to use it anymore - but truth is I still find it very convenient to programmatically parse the "live" objects' code whenever the need arises.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: +1 for your helpful comment, however, you can give a man a fish and he can eat today, or...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The portable way is to use the ANSI/ISO view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`, but you'll only get the first 4000 characters of the stored procedure definition:

```
declare @source_code varchar(max)

select @source_code = t.ROUTINE_DEFINITION
from information_schema.routines t
where specific_schema = 'owner-schema'             -- e.g., dbo
  and specific_name   = 'my_stored_procedure_name' -- your stored procedure name here
```

Or you can use the system view `sys.sql_modules` in the same vein:

```
declare @source_code varchar(max)

select @source_code = definition
from sys.sql_modules
where object_id = object_id('dbo.my_stored_procedure_name')
```

Or, the simplest way:

```
declare @source_code varchar(max)
set @source_code = object_definition( 'dbo.my_stored_procedure_name' )
```

Comment: Except if the procedure is > 4000 characters, you'll get an arbitrary chunk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. I even forgot to argue about this fact when I presented [several other reasons to avoid the portable solution a few years ago](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx). The right way to do this in SQL Server is using `sys.sql_modules` or `object_definition()`.

Comment: The documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx) for the column `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.ROUTINE_DEFINITION` states that it "*returns the first 4000 characters of the definition text of the function or stored procedure if the function or stored procedure is not encrypted. Otherwise, returns NULL.*" Since the underlying data is stored as `varchar(max)`, any behavior other than simple truncation would be surprising. But I can't say I've ever tested things.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was confusing the bad behavior of INFORMATION_SCHEMA with the bad behavior of sys.syscomments. However it's not varchar(max) - the definition is stored in the underlying catalog as **n**varchar(max), but information_schema truncates it to nvarchar(4000).

Comment: the saga continues on [SO21724490: extract a string from a stored proc definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724490/extract-a-string-from-a-stored-proc-definition)

Comment: @Philip: see my [answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21737650/467473)

Answer (score 3):

Nicholas Carey's third option needs some changes,

object_definition function needs object_id as parameter,

so the code should be

```
declare @source_code varchar(max)
declare @objectid int
select @objectid=object_id('dbo.my_stored_procedure_name')
select @source_code = object_definition(@objectid )
```

Check to this link more details
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176090.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the system stored procedure [`sp_helptext`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx) to get the stored procedure definition into a table and then just query against that temp table / table variable something like this..

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(Line_Number INT IDENTITY(1,1), Text_Column NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @TABLE(Text_Column)
EXECUTE sp_helptext Your_Proc_Name

SELECT * 
FROM @TABLE
WHERE Text_Column LIKE '%BOCTEST%'
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT p.name
      ,m.[definition]
FROM  sys.procedures p 
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m
ON    P.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
WHERE m.[definition] LIKE '%BOCTEST%'
```

Comment: This is not a good idea at all. You know there will be a separate row for *each line* in the procedure, right? How do you expect to query from this table in any meaningful way?

Comment: @AaronBertrand What do you think about this one?? this solution can help the user to locate the word he is trying to find in procedure's definition ?

Comment: This will tell the user 1) 1st if the word `BOCTEST` exists in a proc's definition. 2) and if it does exists approximately on which line it exists.

Comment: Now how does he `loop through several procedures`? How does your table tell them which procedure a certain line came from? Also can you guarantee that the IDENTITY value will be generated in the order you expect? Why bother with a table and old sp_ procedures that produce undesirable output when you can use newer catalog views and functions for this?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I really appreciate you'er feedback I have used the `sys.procedures`catalogue view and the `OBJECT_DEFINITION()` function. do you reckon this is a better approach than the last one ?

Comment: I actually prefer a simple join to `sys.sql_modules`, at least it will obey transaction isolation semantics (which the `OBJECT_*` functions do not) and will work with database prefixes too.

Comment: Would you care to leave a comment whoever has down voted this answer ??