# extract a string from a stored proc definition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, substring, patindex, charindex

I need to check the library used by several stored procs that extract data from a remote server.

I have (with SO help, see [SO 21708681](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708681/get-the-text-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server)) built the below code:

```
DECLARE @tProcs TABLE
    (
        procID int IDENTITY,
        procObjectID nvarchar(100),
        procName nvarchar(100)
    );

insert into @tProcs     
SELECT object_id, name 
    FROM sys.objects 
        WHERE  type in (N'P', N'PC') and name like '%_Extract'

declare @countProcs int, @I int=0

select @countProcs=COUNT(*) from @tProcs

while @I<@countProcs
    Begin
        declare @source_code nvarchar(max)
        declare @objectID nvarchar(50)
        declare @proc_Name nvarchar(200)

        select @objectID=procObjectID from @tProcs where procID=@I
        select @proc_Name=procName from @tProcs where procID=@I

        select @source_code = definition
            from sys.sql_modules
            where object_id = @objectID 

        SELECT PATINDEX('BOCTEST.%', @proc_Name) as Pos, @proc_Name 

              -- or SELECT charindex(@source_code, '%BOCTEST%') 

        set @I=@I+1
    End
```

Inside each of the target stored procs there is a line like this:

```
DECLARE YP040P_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM BOCTEST.S653C36C.LIVEBOC_A.YP040P
```

I need to know for each of the stored procs the part 'LIVEBOC_A' (which can either be 'LIVEBOC_A' or LIVEBOC_B)

I tried to use PATINDEX and CHARINDEX to get the location of the start opf that string in the definition from `sysmodules` but all I get back is either zero or an error that string or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: Do you need to know the start position or just whether it's A or B?

Comment: @TI - in fact I really just need to know if it's `LIVEBOC_A` or `LIVEBOC_B` so I want really to create a UDF that will return the correct library to my other queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    table_name = CASE WHEN OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%BOCTEST.S653C36C.LIVEBOC_A.YP040P%' THEN 'LIVEBOC_A'
                      WHEN OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%BOCTEST.S653C36C.LIVEBOC_B.YP040P%' THEN 'LIVEBOC_B' END
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.[type] IN ('P', 'PC')
AND name like '%_Extract'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with a query like this one:

```
select name         = s.name + '.' + p.name ,
       dt_created   = p.create_date ,
       dt_modified  = p.modify_date ,
       livboc_usage = case
                        when m.definition like '%declare%cursor%boctext.[^.].LIVEBOC_A.%' then 'A'
                        when m.definition like '%declare%cursor%boctext.[^.].LIVEBOC_B.%' then 'B'
                        else null
                      end
from sys.schemas     s
join sys.procedures  p on p.schema_id = s.schema_id
join sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = p.object_id
```

But since what you're looking for are cross-server dependencies of a table, you should be able to get that simply by querying the system view [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), which

> Contains one row for each by-name dependency on a user-defined entity in the current
>   database. A dependency between two entities is created when one entity, called the
>   referenced entity, appears by name in a persisted SQL expression of another entity,
>   called the referencing entity. For example, when a table is referenced in the definition
>   of a view, the view, as the referencing entity, depends on the table, the referenced
>   entity. If the table is dropped, the view is unusable.
>
> You can use this catalog view to report dependency information for the following
>   entities:
>
> - Schema-bound entities.
> - Non-schema-bound entities.
> - Cross-database and cross-server entities.
>     Entity names are reported; however, entity IDs are not resolved.
> - Column-level dependencies on schema-bound entities.
>     Column-level dependencies for non-schema-bound objects can be returned
>     by using sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities.
> - Server-level DDL triggers when in the context of the master database.

To that end, running a query like this in the database the referencing stored procedures live should do you:

```
select name              = o.name      ,
       type              = o.type_desc ,
       liveboc_usage     = case d.referenced_schema_name
                             when 'liveboc_a' then 'A'
                             when 'liveboc_b' then 'B'
                             else                  null
                           end ,
       has_dependency_on =       d.referenced_server_name
                         + '.' + d.referenced_database_name
                         + '.' + d.referenced_schema_name
                         + '.' + d.referenced_entity_name
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
join sys.objects                     o on o.object_id = d.referenced_id
join sys.schemas                     s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
where d.referenced_server_name   =    'BOCTEST'
  and d.referenced_database_name =    'S653C36C'
  and d.referenced_schema_name   like 'LIVEBOC_[AB]'
  and d.referenced_entity_name   =    'YP040P'
```