# Extracting data from sp_helptext

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, data-extraction

I am currently pulling the description for 370 procedures using sp_helptext. What I am wondering if any one has a concept on how I would be able to pull the procedure description for each ap (which I have in an excel list) without having to manually go through them each?

Comment: what sort of information do you have in the description? is that the same across?

Comment: possible duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708681/get-the-text-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server

Comment: @maSTAShuFU the description is along the lines of - _Description: Selects the specified supplier id's details_. They are all similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then this can be done using the system function OBJECT_DEFINITION as below:

```
select 
    [name] as 'SP Name', 
    object_definition(object_id) as 'SP Definition'
from sys.procedures
where type = 'P'
```

Will return all stored procedures name and source code.

Can also be found in the sys.sql_modules catalog view for the definition column.

```
select 
    [definition] as 'SP Definition'
from sys.sql_modules
where [definition] like '%procedure%'
```